# how to place a common title for all the pages in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am trying to make a windows phone app. In this I want to place a common title for all of the pages. Please suggest how possible it is.

Comment: Per max's answer, you're question isn't entirely clear. Are you wanting global values, as max suggests, or a page template, in which case you can subclass your page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want but i would say if you want to a common name, say your company name at all the pages. Then all you need to do is to change the application title at every page when you create new one. or if you want to change by code, subscribe to loaded event and write

```
ApplicationTitle.Text = "company-name";
```